# Google AppEngine Blobstore: Downloading a Blob by Filename in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob, blobstore

Suppose I've uploaded a bunch of files (images in this case, if it matters) to GAE's BlobStore.
Later, I want to be able to download those files from somewhere else.
I know that I can use BlobStoreService's serve method to grab a blob by BlobKey, but how do I get the blobkey associated with a given filename?
I can't seem to find any built-in functionality for this.

Comment: What if two of your users upload files with the same name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[BlobInfo](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobInfo.html) metadata that contains the filename attribute is stored in read-only `__BlobInfo__` entities in the datastore.

```
Query query = new Query("__BlobInfo__"); 
query.addFilter("filename", FilterOperator.EQUAL, filename); 
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService(); 
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query); 
List<Entity> entList = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1)); 
String name = entList.get(0).getKey().getName();
```

Comment: which is basically what i said.

Comment: @jtahlborn Specifics - and even better, sample code - count for a lot.

Comment: @Nick Johnson - my answer was sufficient for anyone who knows anything about app engine to solve their problem.  if the user actually required this full answer, then their question should have been "how do i query a model object in app engine".  2 different questions.

Comment: @jtahlborn I, and at least two others, would appear to disagree.

Comment: @jtahlborn So what you're saying is that you knew the complete answer, you were just too lazy to provide it? You shouldn't be surprised your answer isn't being upvoted.

Comment: @Nick - i know lots of stuff about app engine that i did not include in the answer.  i didn't include a complete tutorial about querying models because i assumed the OP had such knowledge and just didn't know what to query.  so, i answered that.

Comment: @Nick - and actually i did provide a complete answer, i just wrote it in english instead of code.  i generally only include a code example when it's non-obvious from the comment.

Comment: @jtahlborn What you posted was a one sentence speculation about what might be possible. Here on SO we value clarity and usefulness, and your answer wasn't really much of either. This answer is clearly far more useful to anyone who doesn't already know the answer to the question they asked.

Comment: @NickJohnson - i see your confusion now.  you took the "i would imagine" part to mean that i was guessing what the answer was.  guess i worded that poorly.  i should have been more declarative.

Answer (score -5):

You can query the BlobInfo objects by filename.