# Setting name to a blobstore in GAE

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to

1. set a name to every blob(image or video) using blob store in GAE and
2. retrieve it later.

How can this be done in  `java` (is given in `Python`). So can anyone tell me how can I do this. How can I use the name to retrieve the blob again?

I want to send and retrieve these images from an android device to the google cloud.
I have posted a similar question before as well but did not got a handy answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a blobkey to get a blob. If you want to use another name (like the filename) you have to store this name and the blobkey to get the blob. Only the blobkey is unique. For instance if you upload the same filename multiple times, these uploaded blobs will have unique blobkeys, but they do not have unique filenames.

See also : [Google AppEngine Blobstore: Downloading a Blob by Filename in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519300/google-appengine-blobstore-downloading-a-blob-by-filename-in-java)